# How to avoid multiple VMs in chrome? (Nextjs)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, next.js, v8, pixi.js

I'm using nextjs to dev locally and I noticed some really strange bugs. (To be specific, I'm developing a PIXI app.) When I dug it, I realized that sometimes there might be multiple VMs running, each with a different state.

For example, I configure my app to output some data whenever I press any key. When I press the key, I got three outputs in the following format:

```
data values 1            VM40504 code.ts:167
data values 2            VM51067 code.ts:167
data values 3                    code.ts:167
```

My guess is that somehow there are three copies of my code running in three different VMs. I have no idea how it ended up in this state. Usually there is only one VM, like if I refresh the page, I got:

```
data values 3                    code.ts:167
```

But after interaction, I ended up with more than one VMs. It seems like the following sequence of action leads to more VMs:

1. switch off to vscode and make some changes
2. because I'm using "yarn dev" to hot load my local change, on command line there is one more line of "✓ Compiled in 107ms (1319 modules)"
3. switch back to the app, now there is another VM

My question is how can I prevent multiple VMs?

Thanks!